# How to refer to an abstract class' method inside a method

Tags: java

Please consider the following code:

```
public Record getRecordByPk(String pkValue) {
        Record record = null;

        Result result = database.query(tableName, recordPkColumn, pkey);
```

The class `Record` is an abstract class that has methods `getTableName` and `getPkColumnName`. There are other classes that extend `Record` and these other classes are what's really returned here. 
How can I refer to these methods and use them instead of the `tableName` and `recordPkColumn` if initialization of abstract classes is not allowed?

Should I use generics? If so then I will do it like:

```
public G getRecordByPk(String pkValue, G recordInstance) {
```

But I do not like having something like a `recordInstance` there just so I could refer to the methods. So what should I do? Or what I am doing is already wrong in the first place?

**Background**

I am writing a simple database application in android. But I think this question is generic in java so I did not add it earlier.

I followed [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) tutorial in creating my DatabaseManager, but my application has more tables so I challenged myself into writing a generic DatabaseManager that can handle all of the tables. I made all these tables inherit from the `Record` abstract class so I can make my DatabaseManager generic. Then I use the `Record` inside the DatabaseManager for the queries.

Comment: You can't call a method of an object without an instance of an object, just like in real life, you can't drive a car if you don't have a car. It looks like you have a serious design problem, but without more code, and without knowing what you want to achieve, it's hard to help more.

Comment: Since these classes extend Record - you can call these methods using objects that were instantiated from these classes

Comment: So in this case, I really need to use generics and do it with the `recordInstance`? I will update the question for some background.

Comment: @Keale what you *really* need is to read the comments above again - until you understand them. Did anyone mention Generics ? Are you trying to solve one thing that you don't understand with another thing that you don't understand ?

Comment: @alfasin sort of, you see i'm trying to play with Generics and Abstracts. Please answer as you see fit.

Comment: Why not simply do it like this?:
public Record getRecordByPk(String pkValue, Record recordInstance) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the questions was:

How can I refer to these methods and use them instead of the `tableName` and `recordPkColumn` if initialization of abstract classes is not allowed?

The answer is:

*You can't call a method of an object without an instance of an object, just like in real life, you can't drive a car if you don't have a car.* - [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it's a bit weird for the `Record` class to return the table name and column names as public methods. I would either use an object factory in case flexibility is needed or a simple hardcoded load() method in case the table name is OK to be hardcoded.